# Laravel not incrementing login value after first run

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to increment a column in my DB every time a user logs on. If i register the user, it successfully sets the count to 0, when they log in for the first time, the count gets incremented by 1, but thats where it stops. Every time a login is made after, the number stays at 1 for some reason.

I am adding the field to the DB using;

```
$table->integer('login_count')->default(0);
```

Then my login controller looks like so;

```
public function login(LoginRequest $request): JsonResponse
{
    $data = $request->validated();

    if (!Auth::attempt($data)) {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Invalid Credentials'], 401);
    }

    Auth::user()->update([
        'last_login' => now(),
        'login_count' => auth()->user()->increment('login_count'),
    ]);

    $token = auth()->user()->createToken('api')->plainTextToken;

    return response()->json([
        'access_token' => $token,
    ]);
}
```

The strange thing is that the last_login field gets updated every time, but the login_count never goes past 1.

I have tried `auth()->user()->login_count++` as well, but still the same result.

I can't figure it out.

Comment: Could you please share your User.php model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `increment()` method is not a helper to "add +1" to an attribute, it's a query builder method that initiate a query. means when you run

```
auth()->user()->increment('login_count')
```

it runs a query that changes the login_count from 1 to 2. This method return 1 as only one record has been updated.

then `Auth::user()->update()` sets login_count back to 1 (the one coming from the `increment()` returned value.

Change your code to

```
Auth::user()->update([
        'last_login' => now(),
        'login_count' => auth()->user()->login_count + 1,
    ]);
```